# Proper instantiation of UISearchDisplayController

Tags: ios, properties, xcode4.6, searchdisplaycontroller

I did some searching and the answer is still unclear to me.   I am trying to create an instance of a UISearchDisplayController inside a TableViewController (TVC).

In the header of my TVC, I declared a searchDisplayController as a property:

```
@interface SDCSecondTableViewController : UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *productList;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *filteredProductList;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UISearchDisplayController *searchDisplayController;

@end
```

Doing so yields the error:

> Property 'searchDisplayController' attempting to use instance variable '_searchDisplayController' declared in super class 'UIViewController'

Adding `@synthesize searchDisplayController` in the implementation file got rid of the errors.

Can anyone please help me understand this error?  I'm using Xcode 4.6.2, but I was under the impression that properties are automatically synthesized starting with Xcode 4.4.

Answer (score 6):

You shouldn't call `[self performSelector:@selector(setSearchDisplayController:) withObject:searchDisplayController];` as LucOlivierDB suggested. That is a private API call that will get your app rejected by Apple (I know because it happened to me).  Instead just do this:

```
@interface YourViewController ()
    @property (nonatomic, strong) UISearchDisplayController *searchController;
@end

@implementation YourViewController

-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    searchBar.delegate = self;

    self.searchController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:searchBar contentsController:self];
    self.searchController.delegate = self;
    self.searchController.searchResultsDataSource = self;
    self.searchController.searchResultsDelegate = self;

    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchBar;
```

}

Comment: There should be no searchController property declared because it'll conflict with the one that UIViewController already has (which gets set inside the init of the UISearchDisplayController).

Answer (score 4):

You are getting this error because [`UIViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) defines a property for `searchDisplayController`. Redefining another property named `searchDisplayController` in your custom class confuses the compiler. If you want to define a `UISearchDisplayController`, instantiate one in the `- (void)viewDidLoad` of your custom class.

Example :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UISearchBar *searchBar = [UISearchBar new];
    //set searchBar frame
    searchBar.delegate = self;
    UISearchDisplayController *searchDisplayController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:searchBar contentsController:self];
    [self performSelector:@selector(setSearchDisplayController:) withObject:searchDisplayController];
    searchDisplayController.delegate = self;
    searchDisplayController.searchResultsDataSource = self;
    searchDisplayController.searchResultsDelegate = self;
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchBar;
}
```

You can refer to the `searchDisplayController` by using `self.searchDisplayController` in your custom class.