# UISearchBar changes its superview when it is added to UITableViewCell on iOS 7.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

In my project i need an `UISearchBar` to scroll on an `UITableView`. So i just put it on an `UITableViewCell` like this:

```
    searchBar                   = [[SearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:cell.bounds];
    searchBar.delegate          = self;
    searchBar.placeholder       = NSLocalizedString(@"Search friends", "");
    searchBar.layer.borderWidth = 1.f;
    searchBar.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;

    sdc = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:searchBar contentsController:nil];
    sdc.delegate = self;

    [cell addSubview:searchBar];
```

and it works fine on iOS 6. But on iOS 7 it switches to another superview (and literally disappears from the screen) when just getting in focus. At first i thought it's something wrong with my project which causes such a behaviour but then i created a simple test project and i verified this - indeed, it's a rule, on iOS 7.1 `UISearchBar` added to `UITableViewCell` moves to another superview and gets lost from the screen right after becoming first responder.

I have overridden `willMoveToSuperview:` method on the search bar and i see that it moves from `UITableViewCellScrollView` to a view which class is `UIView` and whose superview's class is `UISearchDisplayControllerContainerView`.

After few hours of search and experiments i'm not able to figure out what causes this behaviour and how to escape it. All i know for sure is that it happens right between calls to these two `UISearchDisplayDelegate` methods: `searchDisplayControllerWillBeginSearch:` and  `searchDisplayControllerDidBeginSearch:`.

Did anyone ever encountered this? Any ideas how to resolve it?

Comment: Instead of using a cell for the search bar, make the search bar the table view's `headerView`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SearchBar disappears from headerview in iOS 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19044156/searchbar-disappears-from-headerview-in-ios-7)

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you need this bizarre way to add `UISearchBar` to `UITableViewCell` to just scroll it? I simply use smthng like this:

```
UISearchBar *mainSearchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 44)];
mainSearchBar.delegate = self;

UISearchDisplayController *searchCon = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:mainSearchBar contentsController:self ];
searchCon.delegate = self;
searchCon.searchResultsDataSource = self;
searchCon.searchResultsDelegate = self;

mainTableView.tableHeaderView = mainSearchBar;
```