# UISearchDisplayController UISearchBar Animation in a UIScrollView under UIPageControl

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller, uipagecontrol

It's a really tough bug to squash, my ObjC-fu is just really beginner and my confidence is crashing the longer I look into this pretty bug...

The App is required to have a view (let's call it `mainView`) with `UIPageControl` and `UIScrollView` in order to have 2 views scrollable horizontally. Hence I have implemented it by adding:

```
// This is added on viewDidLoad...
[self addChildViewController:[self.storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VC1"]];
[self addChildViewController:[self.storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VC2"]];

// Further processing of the child view controllers...
self.scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;

for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [self.childViewControllers count]; i++) {
    UIViewController *controller = [self.childViewControllers objectAtIndex:page];
    CGRect frame = self.scrollView.frame;
    frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * page;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    controller.view.frame = frame;
    [self.scrollView addSubview:controller.view];
}

// Expanding scroll view's content size for scrolling...
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(
    scrollView.frame.size.width * [self.childViewControllers count], 
    scrollView.frame.size.height);
```

Note that `mainView` is itself equipped with `UISearchDisplayController` having a `UISearchBar` hidden offscreen. (Not sure if this information is vital.)

The problem is in the second child view controller with identifier VC2 is also equipped with `UISearchDisplayController` having a `UISearchBar`, and when the search bar dismisses on end searching, the animation some how make the VC2's `UISearchBar` to reposition in `CGRect(0, 0, 320, 40)` of `mainView` instead of VC2. Hence the VC2's `UISearchBar` "warped" back into VC1.

First attempt to solve this is containing each child view controller in another view hoping the `CGRect(0, 0, 320, 40)` of VC2's `UISearchBar` will remain back in VC2, but to no avail:

```
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [self.childViewControllers count]; i++) {
    UIViewController *controller = [self.childViewControllers objectAtIndex:page];
    CGRect frame = self.scrollView.frame;
    frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * page;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    //controller.view.frame = frame;
    UIView *container = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [container addSubview:controller.view];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:container];
}
```

Somehow I am guessing when VC2's `UISearchDisplayController` animates it's `UISearchBar` the `frame` that it uses are actually the one of `self.UIScrollView` but I am not sure.

Could anyone please shed some light on this bug and burn it to death please? It's in iOS7

```
     Main View
-------------------
|      VC1        |       VC2
-------------------------------------
|                 |_________________| <- Search Bar (This will 'warped' to VC1 at the same
|                 |                 |    position on end editing)
|                 |                 |
|                 |                 |
|                 |                 |
|                 |                 |
|                 |                 |
|                 |                 |
|                 |                 |
|                 |                 |
-------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution, weird, but it works, got the idea from [SearchBar disappears from headerview in iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19044156/searchbar-disappears-from-headerview-in-ios-7/20908981#20908981) after noticing that the memory address of the `UISearchBar`'s superview was changed on end search.

The following code snippet was added any of the delegated methods possible, namely `viewWillAppear`, `searchDisplayControllerWillEndSearch:`, `searchDisplayControllerDidEndSearch:`:

```
if (self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.superview != self.searchDisplayController.searchContentsController.view) {
    [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar removeFromSuperview];
    [self.searchDisplayController.searchContentsController.view addSubview:self.searchDisplayController.searchBar];
}
```

Will accept this as an answer but still should there be anything wrong with this do share. Thank you very much.